# Problems in uploading huge csv files in phpmyadmin php.ini and mysql.cnf checked out

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

i would ask some help for this issue of mine.

I am using phpmyadmin and i need to upload huge CSV files (that is 40 MB more or less); I have had many problems with phpmyadmin but I have solved many of them, in order:

> I have changed the upload size values in php.ini 
>   I have changed the packet sizes in mysql.cnf 
>   I have checked the time out variable which is 28,800 seconds (by deafult) 
>   htaccess does not exist on my pc (i am using phpmyadmin on local host)

Now, having put huge sizes (200 M) I manage to upload up to 20 MB csv files, but when I try to upload a file which is 42 MB the importing starts and after 60 seconds or less the screen goes blank, I can see the choices on the left and currently browse phpmyadmin but the file is not uploaded.

No error is displayed

Can anyone give me some help? Also, the display error switch in php.ini is ON (by default).

Answer (score 0):

You should also set `max_input_time` in php.ini

The important settings in php.ini are:

`upload_max_filesize`
`post_max_size`
`max_execution_time`
`max_input_time`

Comment: Opening the php.ini file I found both max_execution_time and max_input_time and changed them up to 300 (from 60), but I am not sure I changed the right line because there are also other lines that mention. For instance, I chamged these: ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 300                                                                                       still it doesn't upload

Comment: What does your phpmyadmin say about the maximum upload file size? (You can find it next to the `Browse` button on the `Import` tab)

Comment: Thank you Nic.It says "(Max: 800MiB)" which is the size I configured to be sure to be able to upload every huge file of mine (one of these files, if not splitted, could actually be 1.2 giga).

Comment: And it still breaks? Perhaps it's a timeout of the webserver? Is it a Apache? mod_f(ast)cgi? If it breaks after a certain time (40secs, 60secs) I would look for a timeout.

Comment: Yes, it's apache, the package is lamp on ubuntu 12.10; any suggestion on where to check timeout? thank you